# Are there negative consequences to using Lost Mode on ipad repeatedly?

Tags: ipad, screen-lock, icloud

My partner sometimes gets excessively distracted by games on their iPad and asks me to hide it from them for a day or two, until they ask for it back.

I'm going to be out of the country for a while, so we hit on the idea of using [iCloud Lost Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2700?locale=en_US):

- We log the ipad into my iCloud account
- I put it in Lost Mode and set an unlock PIN
- When they ask to use it, I tell them the PIN.
- When they want it taken away again, I reactivate Lost Mode with a new PIN.

**Main Question: Does anyone know if there are any negative consequences to activating Lost Mode on a device repeatedly?** (say, every 1-2 days for 2 weeks)

My concern is that Apple might trigger other security features if the device is reported lost over and over, similar to the way some websites will lock your account if they see repeated attempts to log in or reset your password.

**Secondary question:** Are there other good methods for remotely locking, unlocking, and relocking an iOS device?

Notes:

- It sounds like this approach will only work if the device doesn't have a regular screen lock PIN. This is acceptable.
- The locking method we use doesn't have to be impossible to circumvent, just difficult.
- I welcome other suggestions for solving the larger problem, but please limit them to technical solutions, rather than psychological ones.